# ggplot2 legend by geometries rather than by aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose that a R package defines S3 classes representing data for
scatter points and lines for fits.  It would be sensible to write the
`autoplot` and `autolayer` methods for both points and lines. Then we
could build a plot with `autoplot` and add stuff with a sequence of
calls to `autolayer`, possibly specifying new colour, fill, linetype
at each call.

```
library(ggplot2)
autolayer.myLines <- function(object, ...) {
    geom_line(data = object,
              mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, colour = .group, linetype = .group))
}
autoplot.myLines <- function(object, ...) {
    ggplot() + autolayer(object, ...)   
}
autolayer.myPoints  <- function(object, ...) {
    geom_point(data = object,
               mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, colour = .group, shape = .group))
}
autoplot.myPoints  <- function(object, ...) {
    ggplot() + autolayer(object, ...)
}

set.seed(123)
xP <- runif(10)
## objects with class "myPoints"
myP1 <- data.frame(x = xP, y = xP + rnorm(10, sd = 0.1), .group = "points 1")
myP2 <- data.frame(x = xP, y = xP * xP + rnorm(10, sd = 0.1), .group = "points 2")
class(myP1) <- class(myP2) <- c("myPoints", "data.frame")

## objects with class "myLines"
xL <- seq(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 80)
myL1 <- data.frame(x = xL, y = xL, .group = "line 1")
myL2 <- data.frame(x = xL, y = xL * xL, .group = "line 2")
class(myL1) <- class(myL2) <- c("myLines", "data.frame")

autoplot(myP1) + autolayer(myL1) + autolayer(myP2) + autolayer(myL2)  +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("orangered", "green", "magenta", "SteelBlue"))
```

[image: With R code]

The nice point is that legends are updated when some new material is
added. However the legend created by the common `colour` keyword is
quite confusing. It would make sense to have only *two* legends, one
for the points and one for the lines each with the elements of the
aesthetics in `geom_point` and `geom_line`. So shapes would be shown
for the "points" legend, but not for the "lines" one, as if the
legends arose from two ggplots using two data frames: one for the
points and one for the lines (see image below). So the question is: what is the best way
to get the two legends, making sure they are updated when more
`autolayer` calls are added?

[image: Wanted legend]

More generally some keywords entering in the definition of aesthetics
via `aes` such as `fill` have a quite different meaning across
geometries and it seems strange to gather these in a common legend as
is the case e.g.  if `geom_ribbon` and `geom_point` are used in the
same plot both with aesthetics including `fill`. Is there a simple
solution to avoid this default behaviour and generate legends from
aesthetics  within geoms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`library(ggnewscale)` helps here:

```r
library(ggnewscale)
autoplot(myP1) + 
    autolayer(myP2) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("magenta", "SteelBlue")) +
    new_scale_color() +
    autolayer(myL1) + 
    autolayer(myL2)  +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "red"))
```

[image: Two Color Scales]

Comment: Nice. Seems very easy to use for non-experts, as wanted.